# How can I Create single vim regular expression map to compile and run c++ program in windows

Tags: c++, vim, nmap, autocmd

in linux i used something like

```
autocmd FileType cpp nmap <buffer> <F5> :w<bar>!g++ -o %:r % && ./%:r<CR>
```

but since windows uses back slashes i thought i should try something like

```
autocmd FileType cpp nmap <buffer> <F5> :w<bar>!g++ -o %:r % && .\\%:r<CR>
```

or

```
autocmd FileType cpp nmap <buffer> <F5> :w<bar>!g++ -o %:r % && ./\%:r<CR>
```

but none of them seem to give desired results .can someone who understands vim scripts better help me figure this out .  I've also tried other combinations but nothing seems to work .rather than gamble  some more thought I might ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the solution i ended up going with, was to not put any preceding backslashes .
See the idea was to run a command terminal command like `.\hello` for  program called hello i assumed its the linux equivalent of `./hello` for any executable. turns out a `hello.exe` file gets created when one compiles so the solution is just to call `hello.exe` with by just typing `hello` in terminal

therefore my final command was with no slashes at all

`autocmd FileType cpp nmap <buffer> <F5> :w<bar>!g++ -o %:r % && %:r<CR>`

as for  a regular expression that creates the previous desired result. Thats still a mystery to me .cheers

Comment: On Windows cmd single dot with backslash .\ before program name is not necessary,  like in Linux, but possible. Note - it is backslash, not slash.

Comment: By the way. Why do you need one hotkey for build and run? What if program build ends with error? It will then run your old version of executable. Dont think it's what you want. I suggest you to use two separate hotkeys: one for :make command and one to run the batch file, which runs program with desired arguments.

Comment: thanks for the tip. As I'm new to c++ development i will keep that in mind .
Although i should point out i have a plugin that checks my syntax before i compile so sofar ive been able to avoid errors in compilation